# Https call inside Kubernetes Pods results tls handshake failure

Tags: kubernetes, ssl

when I call a https URL inside a Kubernetes Pod I get tls handshake error.

this is curl result in pod:

```
# curl -v https://google.com
*   Trying 104.21.41.20:443...
* Connected to google.com (104.21.41.20) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* OpenSSL/3.0.9: error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL/3.0.9: error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I checked curl on Kubernetes Nodes and everything is fine. this happens just in Pods.

My Kubernetes version is v1.27.0, Also I am using Flannel as a network manager

Comment: Check your DNS service (CoreDNS) if it's running without errors or not. Also use this guide [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) to troubleshoot the DNS issues.

Comment: @nariman amani  - any updates? did you understand the problem?

Comment: @EranY I had to change the network plugin from Calico to Flannel and the problem solved